# How do I change json string text into integers, that could be extracted for data collection?

Tags: python, api

*solved

I'm following Sentdex Python GUI tutorial and we want to connect with API, extract data and then show it on graph. Video is a little bit outdated and the site he was using is gone, so I had to use another one (Bitfinex), but principles stay the same. I'm stuck at following problem:

https://youtu.be/uK7wAvS8C0U?t=15m33s

https://docs.bitfinex.com/v1/reference#rest-public-trades (public API)

```
def animate(i):
    dataLink = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/trades/BTCUSD"

    response = requests.request("GET", dataLink)

    print(response.text)

    data = urllib.request.urlopen(dataLink) #this is in bytes, we have to decode
    data = data.readline().decode("utf-8")
    data = json.loads(data)
    data = data["BTCUSD"]
    data = pd.DataFrame(data) #now data is pandas data set
```

I get a following problem:

```
  File "C:/Users/kleme/PycharmProjects/GUIs with Tkinter/GUI.py", line 46, in animate
data = data["BTCUSD"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I've googled and tried out few different things on my own already, but I still can't get it right. I'm also not sure, if I'm using API wrong or something else, but if I understand correctly and looking at python, it returns to us a string list, as such

```
[{"timestamp":1530514714,"tid":264164749,"price":"6312.1","amount":"0.025","exchange":"bitfinex","type":"sell"}, etc..
```

but now I just have to put it into integer type. I know you can do data type conversion with int() and I've tried couple of things with it already, but still, as said couldn't get anything to make this thing run correctly and display real-time graph.

It's supposed to extract data and show it on graph, but graph is just blank, since it can't extract int from that response.text that is returning string type data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rakesh the API returns a list of dicts, not a dict.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
data = data["BTCUSD"]
```

is actually totally useless. In the JS snippet in the doc it's as an argument to the client used to build the url, but you're not concerned about it since it's already part of your url:

```
dataLink = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/trades/BTCUSD"
```

so after the `json.loads()` call you already have a list of dicts that you can work with.

As as side note, this:

```
data = data.readline().decode("utf-8")
```

is brittle at best - you shouldn't assume all the content is crammed on a single line, it could has well contains newlines characters. But actually since you already have `requests` installed you should just get rid of the `urllib` part completely and just use `response.json()`:

```
dataLink = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/trades/BTCUSD"

response = requests.request("GET", dataLink)
data = response.json()
# now `data` is a list of dicts, you can pass it to panda or do whatever with it.
```

Comment: If I do this, I get TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'.

Comment: @KL no you dont - unless of course you pass `data` to `json.loads()`, which is useless and will indeed raise this exact error since `response.json()` ALREADY convert the json to Python. Why do you think I mentionned it in the comment in the last line of the code snippet ?

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that. But now I got: TypeError: loads() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but it looks like you just don't understand what you are doing... YOU DONT HAVE TO USE `json.loads()`  __AT ALL__, `response.json()` ALREADY TAKES CARE OF IT !!!

Comment: I got it, it extracts now. Sorry, I'm already confused by going through this crash course really fast and learning everything. 

Ty, but now that it extracts I got other problems and it doesn't show graph correctly. 

raise ValueError('If using all scalar values, you must pass'
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: @KL if it solved your problem, then mark it as solved and ask another question about your new problem. Still if you ask me, don't try to learn fast, because you don't seem to know what you are doing at all.

Comment: Just what @BcK said... If you don't understand what you're doing then you are NOT learning anything.